# If two range criteria are met, copy a third cell and paste it to another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have a sheet called "Scores" where I have Column D and J with values from 1-9 in both columns.

In this same sheet I have a Column A with the corresponding name for that row (i.e Andrew).

What I need to do is basically a matrix with three possible ranges, which are 1-3, 4-6 and 7-9.

- If D is within 1-3, and simultaneously J is 1-3, Column A for that row will go to a specific range of cells in another sheet called "Box",
- if D is 1-3 and simultaneously J 4-6, Column A for that row will go to another range of cells in "Box",
- If D is 1-3 and simultaneously J is 7-9 it will go to another range of cells in "Box".
- The same thought process applies to all the different ranges (i.e D.3-5 with J.1-3, and so on)

I am attaching an example sheet for better clarification.

[Example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eZKRMmKsDcCJl8M8baLXNTn-Fq495_W3RvCuN9cRX5g/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code for me site, please include the code you have tried in the original post.  As is this is too broad for this forum.

Comment: I have corrected the example link. And the code, I am very new to VBA and I am trying to learn as it goes. I have a very simple code I am trying, maybe I should post that?

Comment: Please do, any attempt to do what you want will show the community that you are trying and not expecting us to do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

I updated your Google Sheets in-place. In GS, this kind of job is straightforward with [`query()`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en).

```
=query(Scores!$A:$J, "select A where D >= 7 and D <= 9 and J >= 7 and J <= 9", 0)
```

Maybe someone will post Excel or VBA answer.